# Is there any bias introduced by evaluating a model and decisions based on this model on the same data set?

Tags: forecasting, model-selection, bias, finance, decision-theory

As an example, let's say we have some financial time series such as closing prices of some stock and we would like to evaluate the ability of different models to forecast future closing prices as well as the ability of a different set of models to make decisions based off of these forecasts, e.g. whether to buy, hold, or sell the stock. Let us also assume that we are going to use this data to evaluate our decisions by utilizing some form of trading strategy backtesting based upon the closing price time series data.

Do we introduce any bias into the evaluation of either our forecasts or decisions based on our forecasts by using the same data for evaluation of both sets of models? Let's assume we do some sort of train/validation/test split on our initial series of closing prices for performance evaluation of both forecasts and decisions.

This example concerns quantitative finance, but I feel as if this generalizes to any situation where we are evaluating both forecasts and decisions made based on those forecasts and wanted to know if there's a common solution to this if it's even a problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you build two prospective trading algorithm on historic data and then evaluate them in the upcoming year, or do you mean building the model on the historic data and then evaluating on the same historic data?

Comment: *Optimism bias* is only one source for mispredictions based on calibration information. That's why out-of-sample validation data is necessary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimism_bias

Comment: Thank you for that point, @MikeHunter . Would it be the case that as long as we abide by general rules for cross-validation (e.g., explore/evaluate performance as much as we need to on training, use the validation for parameter tuning, and ideally only evaluate against the test set once per model, etc.) for each goal (forecast evaluation and decision evaluation) that we should then be "okay" with regards to common biases introduced?

Comment: You wiill have met the minimum required hurdles for validating your model, yes.

Comment: @Dave apologies, didn't see this until now, I think I mean the latter, for example, let's say we have a year of daily closing prices for some stock, I am meaning that I would attempt to create a forecasting model from this data (after splitting it up for cross-validation) and then evaluate a decision model (decisions to buy/sell/hold the stock based on said forecasts) on this same set of data (again after splitting it up for cross-validation).